# Configuring simplelogger (slf4j) on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, slf4j, system.out

I have a tomcat 7 running on a windows machine as a service. there's a rolling deployment scheme active, where if I drop a war file in the tomcat/webapps folder, it gets unpacked and deployed automatically. My war file looks like this:

```
MyApp.war
+- META-INF
+- WEB-INF
   +- classes
       + com.company... (the actual class files)
       +-simplelogger.properties
   +- lib
       +- slf4j-api-1.7.12
       +- slf4j-simple-1.7.12
   +- web.xml
```

In my simplelogger.properties I have this output property:

> org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=System.out

A previous version of the war used `system.out.println()` to do "logging", and everything that was wirrten to sysout was appended to the file `tomcat/logs/stdout.log`, so I assume this is standard tomcat behaviour.

Unfortunately, my new setup doesn't work. The logging does not appear in the stdout.log file. It does work fine when I run the war in eclipse with the maven/tomcat plugin.

What configuration details have I missed? 
I looked in the `tomcat/conf` folder for anything that deals with logging and I found the following:

- In catalina.properties: nothing about logging.
- In server.xml: nothing about logging
- logging.properties: I see alot of settings, but nothing related to sysout or stdout.logs. For reference, here is the [full file](http://pastebin.com/5bJ5JjQP).

Answer (score -1):

You have to set up the 'console appender' to lead the System.out output to the log file.

A basic configuration in your log4j.xml would be as follows:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
 <errorHandler class="org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
 <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
 <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
 <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
 </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: I'm not using log4j, and neither was there any log4j.xml file before I added the slf4 api. So something else must have made the sysout.out statements go to stdout.log. I'm trying to use the simplelogger instead of any other bindings to achieve the same effect.